# Forcing (Py)Spark to distribute partitions to all executors in a balanced way

Tags: python, apache-spark

So I am loading a dataframe, ~5 million rows, ~80 columns.

One of the columns, let's call it X has ~17000 unique string values, with nice and even distribution of the value counts (i.e. no value of X is too frequent).

I want to group the data by X and do some aggregate metrics for the rest of the columns. So I thought it would be good idea to repartition on X first and cache the data.

```
df.repartition(400, 'X')
df.cache().count()
```

However, ***all the cached data end up on a single executor***, which is very much not ideal for the subsequent analysis.

Interestingly, after removing the partitioning on 'X':

```
df.repartition(400)
df.cache().count()
```

The data is nicely and evenly distributed across all the nodes.

Questions:

- why does the cached data partitioned on X end up on single executor?
- in general, is there a way to redistribute the cached data in a balanced way among all the nodes?

  - I am thinking especially of situations when using dynamic allocation - one can suddenly get new fresh nodes which would thus have no data, leaving all the work to the already present nodes...

Comment: Ok, so I think I found an partial answer to the first of my questions. It seems to do with spark optimizing for data locality (why it results in all data being on the same machine, I don't know), as doing `spark.conf.set('spark.locality.wait', 0)` before the `repartition` call will end up distributing the data properly to all nodes. Still interested in the answer to the second question and more know-how what's happening under the hood!

Comment: I had similar issue and I researched 'spark.locality.wait' parameter. I found [this](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/208237373-FAQ-When-is-it-a-good-idea-to-set-Spark-locality-wait-to-zero-) article very helpful. My understanding is that your case could be that spark was trying to process data close to where it was stored and that's why it was so concentrated in few executors. When you turned off locality, it started to focus more on availibility of executors and distributing data evenly. This could not work if you had very big dataset where data transfer would be more costly.

Comment: Thanks Piotr, that's quite useful. Would be still interested to know how to redistribute cached data once new executors join the cluster.