# Spark: Distribute low number of compute-intensive tasks via UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a spark cluster with 5 worker nodes available for computation (in Azure Databricks). However, the task I need to solve is different from a typical spark use case: Instead of having a simple task that needs to be applied to millions of rows, I have to run a very complex operation on 60 rows of data.

My intention is to basically distribute the 60 tasks to the 5 workers, so that each worker processes `60/5 = 12` tasks. For this to work, I understand that the number of executors should equal the number of workers. This seems to be the case, as indicated by running

```
num_executors = len(spark.sparkContext._jsc.sc().statusTracker().getExecutorInfos()) - 1
# returns 5
```

Here is some naive pseudocode that runs, but only on a single worker:

```
def my_complex_function(input):
  # this function uses all available cores (internally parallelized)
  # and takes about 15 minutes to complete per call if run on a 
  # single worker node
  do_stuff(input_row)
  write_output_to_file(stuff)
  return(debug_message)

UDF_function = udf(lambda z: my_complex_function(input_row), StringType())
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=["data"])

# sdf contains 60 rows and a single column, "data".
# "data" is just a path to blob storage file that needs to be processed.

sdf_new = sdf.withColumn("output", UDF_function(col("data")))
display(sdf_new) # <- Triggers the computation
```

As mentioned, this seems to run on a single worker only. I assume that this is because as my dataset is so small, it is not distributed to different workers - I attempted to fix this with:

```
sdf = sdf.repartition(num_executors)
```

However, this still does not work. Only a single worker is used, as indicated by Spark UI and my logfiles.

**What do I need to set in order to simply have each of the executors run their share of tasks, in parallel?**

Comment: Are you doing a `sdf_new.collect()` to trigger the computation?

Comment: Ah, forgot that line: I am doing `display(sdf_new)` to trigger the computation.

Comment: I tried `spark.locality.wait 0` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55749095/forcing-pyspark-to-distribute-partitions-to-all-executors-in-a-balanced-way#comment98175061_55749095), but that did not change anything.

Comment: What happens when you do a `sdf_new.collect()` instead of a `display`?

Comment: Holy cow, it looks like you are on to something. I will wait a bit to see whether this actually runs through, but it looks like it is suddenly using all workers. Do you have any resources / links where I can read about why this is happening, or was it just a guess? Looks like my understanding of Spark is even worse than I thought...

Comment: To save on compute resources, it makes good sense for the `display` function not to schedule a complete evaluation of a huge df if it only need to show 1000 rows. Especially if you are sharing a cluster that already has high utilization. I have been stuck in almost the same situation as you, where the `display` function was the culprit. Would be nice if somebody from databricks could give some concrete details on how the `display` function works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `display` function is speculating in scheduling as few tasks as possible in order to produce its output that is capped at 1000 rows. It starts by scheduling one task, and hope for that to be enough. Then 4, 20... and so on. That takes a long time in your case.

You can try collecting everything at the driver instead:

```
sdf_new.collect()
```

By collecting everything at the driver, you are for sure triggering a complete evaluation of your dataframe.

Comment: Still running, but it looks like this was indeed the solution. Thank you so much! Your answer probably saved me multiple hours worth of debugging headaches.

Comment: It worked. An additional note for anyone who stumbles upon this: Turns out that parallelization on multiple cores doesn't work optimally on Databricks for compute-intensive tasks. I don't know the reason, but after setting `spark.executor.cores 1` and `spark.executor.instances` to the number of instances, and `spark.executor.memory` to an appropriately low value (this is important), it perfectly parallelizes and I have 100% CPU usage for all nodes. Just make sure to repartition your dataset to the number of executors.